# How can I include the period (.) in Vim's search and replace command? (replacing .html extensions)?

Tags: vim, replace

When I do: `/.html` Vim looks for `html`

I would like to replace all the `.html` with `.php`

Something like this: `:%s/html ext/php ext/g`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Escape it. The `.` is a regex character which means "any character", so you need to escape it with `\`.

```
:%s/\.html/.php/g
```

Comment: Note that the `.` is for any character **except** a new line.

Answer (score 5):

Just escape the `.` character.

Search for `/\.html`

Answer (score 5):

Try escaping period character: `/\.html`

Answer (score 1):

Use backslach to escape the dot.

`/\.html` will look for ".html".